# Frequency of a term or keyword, over time

Tags: discussion, data-analysis, trends

This might sound like a strange request, but here's what I'd like to do:

Know how often a certain keyword or tag is used, over time, on StackOverflow.

For example, for this keyword: "github"

How many times was it mentioned in Jan 2012, Feb 2012, March 2012, etc.

Similar to Google Trends:
http://www.google.com/trends/?q=github

I'm looking for up-and-coming technologies and things that are trending.  I assume that the number of mentions of a word would be an interesting indicator.

Comment: We're pretty well obsessed with analyzing data. Know any SQL? You should familiarize yourself with [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I've got so far: [Tag usage by week](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76895/tag-usage-by-week)

It's a relatively slow query since it looks at all questions ever.

Comment: Wow, cool!  I tried it with keyword "github" and the sum of all weeks was 3,073.  Then, I went to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github  and it says "3,398 questions tagged [with github]".  Any idea why there might be a difference?

Comment: The Data Explorer uses a separate copy of the data to avoid hurting site performance. It only gets updated every month or two.